# Why doesn't x86-64 long mode need segmentation?

Tags: operating-system

X86_64 long mode(64bit) does not need segmente selector. Why is segmentation necessary in 32bit but useless in 64bit?
Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CPU in X86_64 long mode uses PAE (Physical Address Extension) technology to control memory.

So segment selector is not necessary.

I recommend you read this pdf manual `AMD64 Architecture Programmer’s Manual Volume 2: System Programming`.

Google `amd64 volume 2`, the first result is the pdf manual.

See Chapter 5.3 `Long-Mode Page Translation`, and you will understand.

Answer (score 2):

Segment selectors were useful when memory was actually loaded and unloaded by segment, which was an option back when x86 was first developed. However, modern operating systems all use paging, which was introduced into x86 later and (despite some tradeoffs) its simplicity eventually led it to displace segmentation.

32-bit x86 kept segmentation available while 16-bit OSes transitioned to the new processor architecture, but during the design of 64-bit x86, some legacy features (including segmentation) were removed. Another feature that is commonly described in OS textbooks but never used in practice is the concept of different permissions "rings". Classically, there are 4 rings (numbered 0-3), but in practice nobody uses anything except for 0 (kernel) and 3 (user space), so x86-64 removed rings 1 and 2. However, to add support for new hypervisor-related instructions, x86-64 introduced a new ring below 0 called -1.

Segmentation makes it more difficult to detect [cache aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947117/definition-meaning-of-aliasing-cpu-cache-architectures) for memory, so supporting it would have also made the design for x86-64 chips more complicated.